# searching error

Tags: java, search

I don't know what's wrong with this code. When I key in the correct `nomatric` that matches, it will display correct but also an error message.

What's wrong?

```
public void Search(int nomatric) {
    for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
        if (student[i].matrix == nomatric) {
            System.out.printf("%-25s%-25s%-25s%-25s%-25s\n", "Matric", "Name", "Course work", "Final exam", "Grade");
            System.out.printf("%-20d %-20s %-20.2f %-20.2f %-20s", student[i].matrix, student[i].name, student[i].coursework, student[i].finalexam, student[i].grade);
            System.out.println();
        }  
    }
    System.out.println("Cannot find the matric number!!!");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: You need to use a variable to take note that you have entered the if statement.

Comment: @RohitJain I think the error message is `Cannot find the matric number!!!`.

Comment: Can you have multiple students having the same value of `matrix`?

Answer (score 2):

Use one flag variable. Set it to false before for loop. Inside the loop, whenever match found, set this flag to true. Out side the loop use if condition on flag. If flag is false means no match found, then only print the error.

```
  public void Search(int nomatric) {
     boolean flag=false;
     for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
     if (student[i].matrix == nomatric) {
        System.out.printf("%-25s%-25s%-25s%-25s%-25s\n", "Matric", "Name", "Course    work", "Final exam", "Grade");
        System.out.printf("%-20d %-20s %-20.2f %-20.2f %-20s", student[i].matrix,    student[i].name, student[i].coursework, student[i].finalexam, student[i].grade);
        System.out.println();
        flag=true;
    }  
 }
 if( ! flag) {
    System.out.println("Cannot find the matric number!!!");
    System.out.println();
 }
}
```

Comment: just a side note, use some meaningful name rather than `flag`

Comment: @Vishal Coding was impromptu. I know its a bad coding practise though. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Manish can you please let me know where I am wrong.?

Comment: @Manish.. Always quote the reason why you feel it's wrong, rather than just throwing your comments open-ended.

Comment: then also let him write the comment as well

Comment: but Vallabh Patade helped me solve my problem already ...

Answer (score 1):

your error message `System.out.println("Cannot find the matric number!!!");` is unconditional in your code, so it will always display that error

Answer (score 1):

You return `void`, so you don't get the convenience of an early, meaningful `return` block.  You do need to indicate that you have entered into the `if` block somehow.  You have two* options:

- Use a boolean to indicate that, if you have entered the `if` block, then you shouldn't print the message, or
- Return `String` from the method instead of printing it implicitly, and have the caller print the return message instead.

(*:  You also have the option of `return`ing from your if statement, although this style isn't recommended.  This would mean, instead of using a `boolean` variable, you place `return` immediately after your `System.out.println()`.)

Rewritten with option one, your method looks like this:

```
public void search(int nomatric) {
    boolean success = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
        if (student[i].matrix == nomatric) {
            success = true;
            System.out.printf("%-25s%-25s%-25s%-25s%-25s\n", "Matric", "Name", "Course work", "Final exam", "Grade");
            System.out.printf("%-20d %-20s %-20.2f %-20.2f %-20s", student[i].matrix, student[i].name, student[i].coursework, student[i].finalexam, student[i].grade);
            System.out.println();
        }  
    }
    if(!success) {

        System.out.println("Cannot find the matric number!!!");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Option two is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: You should move that `assignment` inside the `if` statement.

Comment: Good catch.  I hadn't realized I did that - not editing this with an external editor this time.

Comment: `You return void, so you don't get the convenience of an early return` --> Wrong. You can always write `return;`

Comment: This is true.  I should probably clarify "meaningful return".  Returning from a void statement is essentially an early break, which goes against most every style guide I've been using.

Comment: My opinion: Coding guideline is to produce human-readable and uniform code. Apart from cosmetic stuffs (indentation, spaces), the rest may be "override" on case-by-case basis - if the code is clearer as a result of not following the guide.

Comment: @nhahtdh:  [Obligatory XKCD on good practice.](http://xkcd.com/292/)  You're right in that good practice can be eschewed, but it shouldn't be.  Getting into the bad habit of that early return can bite you down the road.

Comment: Well, you can't return early if there are multiple matches.